# Child To Parent Value access using ViewChild

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms, viewchild

I have read about articles in angular6, 3 ways to communicate in  child to parent.if its wrong,please demonstrate if possible
1)output emitter
2)using viewchild
3)shared Service.

So here i need to understand how to communicate the viewchild from child to parent.

In below demo, have created a form in child component,when child component form is valid, that should be reflected in parent component.In this demo when components gets loaded in ngafterViewInit hook the view child value , its working as expected , but when  type some thing , child component form  is valid,button enabled in child form ,those changes not reflected in  the parent component  which needs to valid , but its not working as expected. can anyone give the best approach?

parent component.html

```
<h1> Parent Component</h1>

<button class="btn btn-danger " disabled="{{check}}">CheckParentEnable</button>
<div class="childComponent">
<app-child-component></app-child-component>
 k2
  </div>
```

parent component.html

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  public check: boolean;
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) myname: ChildComponent;


  constructor() {

  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.check = this.myname.loginForm.valid;
  }

}
```

Child.component.html

```
<h4>childComponentArea<h4>

  <h1>Welcome to child component</h1>


<form [formGroup]="loginForm">

<input type="email" formControlName="email" placeholder="Email" >

<button class="btn btn-danger" [disabled]="loginForm.invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

child.component.ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input,Output, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup,Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-component',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm:FormGroup;
  name:string ='sahir';
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }


 private createForm() {
    this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
      // tslint:disable-next-line
      email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])

    });
  }

  k8

}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-viewchild?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Your question is worded backwards according to your code logic. This is `Parent to Child` communication not `Child to Parent`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need `ngAfterViewChecked` life cycle hook for your requirement. `ngAfterViewInit` of parent wont be called for every child component value changed, instead `ngAfterViewChecked` would be called. And also you need to push the `change detection` within parent into `ViewChecked` life cycle hook, or else you will get `ExpressionChanged` error in this line.

```
this.check = this.myname.loginForm.valid;
```

So this is the code that should work

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewChecked, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
constructor(private cdr : ChangeDetectorRef) {

}

ngAfterViewChecked() {
     console.log('view checked')
     this._check = this.myname.loginForm.valid;
     console.log(this.myname.loginForm.valid);
     this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

An also instead of `disabled="{{check}}"`, use `[disabled]="!check"`

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-viewchecked-parent-child)